# Where/How can I download all proteins in the UniProt with signal peptide annotated?

Tags: uniprot

Where/How can I download all proteins in the UniProt with signal peptide annotated? I downloaded the uniref50.xml. However, the annotation information is not contained.

In an XML record of a protein, the signal peptide information is contained in `<feature type="signal peptide" evidence="2"> </feature>`. The uniref.xml does not have this information. uniprot annotates this feature with signalp mainly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect that the signal peptide should be annotated there? Can you point us to more information about how uniprot annotates such features?